# ASP.net Connect to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Hi guys I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL database with ASP.net! I've created a Database containing 3 tables, but every time I try and connect to the database I receive an error message stating I must obtain permission first... How do I connect or get the permission?

Windows Authentication

error

you do not have permission to open this file

contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission

Comment: What type of login system does your database have? Windows authentication? Also, please post your connection string.

Comment: And if I may add, i'm struggling with the connection string. How do I obtain the connection String?

Comment: Review this http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 for connection string examples.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your string connection with `IntegratedSecurity = true`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.integratedsecurity.aspx

Nota : information current Windows account credentials are used for authentication

Nota : you can also use server account (false), but you must specify in your string connection

Another link about build string connection : http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

Try something different such as enabling "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" in SQL Management Studio
Right click the Server node => Properties => Security

Then create a new SQL user profile with full permissions to your database and use those credentials in you connection string.

Answer (score -2):

You Application Pool Identity must have enough permission to access your db.

Comment: You can run the application pool identity as anything you want, it absolutely doesn't need to be running under Network Service.